# Why should `amount` be sent to BrainTree PayPal Configuration when using the `Drop-In`?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, braintree, nonce

I am wondering why we must send the `amount` of money during requesting the nonce when we using BrainTree Drop-In with PayPal payment method. I found that this value is not being used at all.

The only value that is being used to determine the amount of money to take is that value I send when using the nonce I received (and it could be anything different than what I send as `amount`).

Here is a simple code:

```
braintree.dropin.create({
    authorization: token,
    container: '#checkout-container',
    paypal: {
        flow: 'checkout',
        amount: '1000000000', // This value is not being used!!!
        currency: 'EUR'
      }
}, callback);
```

Does anyone know why we should send this value if it is not being used?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

In using the [PayPal Checkout workflow](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/checkout-with-paypal/javascript/v3) - `flow: "checkout"` - you're authorizing PayPal to charge that amount to the customer. The `amount` is required and will return an [error](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/blob/d225196481957a5337c1dd0e3e12eb2c9776a3db/src/views/payment-sheet-views/base-paypal-view.js#L56GitHub) if not included.

`amount` is not required for the [PayPal Vault workflow](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/vault/javascript/v3) - `flow: "vault"` - because you are creating a billing agreement with the customer to charge them any amount in the future.

For more info on the two different PayPal workflows, check out [Braintree's documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/overview/javascript/v3).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that does not answer the question. The question is when I enter a value in `amount` which does not match the value I am using in braintree drop-in, that `amount` is just ignored. In other words, that `amount` is just not being used.

Comment: And in the above situation I DO use `checkout flow`.